# which one of the following set of function is not orthogonal(with respect to the $L^2$ -inner product) over the given interval

Tags: real-analysis

Which one of the following  set of  function  is not orthogonal(with respect to the $L^2$ -inner product) over the given interval

$a)\{\sin n x : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ , $-\pi < x < \pi$

$b) \{\cos nx : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $-\pi < x < \pi$

$c) \{x^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, $-1 < x < 1 $

$d) \{x^{2n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} : -1 < x <1$

---

My  attempt :  I know that  two function $f_m(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ are orthogonal  if  $$\int_{a}^{b} f_m(x).f_n(x)dx =0 ,$$ for $m \neq n$

For  a)  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin nx \sin mx dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(n-m)x -\cos(n+m)x dx= 0$

similarly for $b)$ we have  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nx \cos mx dx =0$

Im confusing about option c) and d)  because  only one option is correct

Any hints/solution

Comment: Have you tried taking elements of the sets and actually plugging them into the integral you wrote? You should be able to compute them and show that they are 0 or not

Comment: I would not call this an "attempt"

Comment: @whpowell96   im confusing  at  option c and option d

Comment: @uniquesolution  sorry  for that

Comment: How do you define $x^{2n+ \frac 1 2} $ when $x<0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  sir  that mean  x will be complex number am i right ?